# How to handle click and doubleclick in Bootgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-bootgrid

My table is Jquery Bootgrid and I want to do an action by clicking and another action by double-clicking a row.

If I click a row, I want to alert the `id` of this row.
If I double-click this row, I want to jump to another url eg. `jump.php?id=[id of this row]`

Can somebody give me tips or an example for my problem?

Comment: I flaged as duplicated because you already know how to handle events with bootgrid. You just need to know how to handle both click and double click in the same element.

Answer (score 0):

Use the dbclick event.

```
$("p").dblclick(function(){
    alert("The paragraph was double-clicked");
});
```

read more on [W3](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_dblclick.asp)